# How to check Windows Service Severity using command line

Tags: windows, service

According to SC CREATE, we can set service severity using **error** parameter e.g.

- error= severe
- error= normal

Refer to [SC CREATE](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc990289(v=ws.11).aspx)

But I can't find the way to check what's current service severity

Purpose: to generate a script for Ops to do post check after change service severity.

Thanks,

Comment: This is reported by `sc qc`.

Comment: @HarryJohnston: many thanks. I didn't see it. I've just tried to use 'sc query'